# Query with czech charset not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, character-encoding

I'm trying to execute these commands:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `ps_product_lang` SET `available_now` = 'Skladem do 10 pracovních dnů';";
$sql = mb_convert_encoding($sql, "UTF-8");
$databaze = new mysqli(_DB_SERVER_,_DB_USER_,_DB_PASSWD_,_DB_NAME_);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        blah blah ...
}
if ($databaze->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    blah blah ...
}
$databaze->close();
```

After executing this code the SQL DB has in it `Skladem do 10 pracovních dnù` instead of `Skladem do 10 pracovních dnů` .. se the difference? ù instead of ů .. we don't even have that weird char `ù` in our alphabet.

Comment: Remove `$sql = mb_convert_encoding($sql, "UTF-8");` and try with `$databaze->set_charset("utf8");` does that help? Also make sure your table charset is `UTF-8`

Comment: Nope, that outputs this: `Skladem do 10 pracovn` .. just cuts before first `í` :/

Comment: If you're looking at it using PHPMyAdmin make sure you click on the edit button as it some times hide part of the saved data.

Comment: I've actually copied whole text data saved there .. nothing more is there saved

Comment: Can you post your table scheme?

Comment: Do you mean screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've after really long time trying many options found the solution:

instead of writing this:

> $sql = mb_convert_encoding($sql, "UTF-8");

there should be written this:

> $sql = mb_convert_encoding($sql, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2");

while you should make sure your text is written in this format `ISO-8859-2` f.e. in your head tag by having this in there: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2"/>`